# Does Kotlin have a BigDecimal setPrecision utility method?

Tags: java, kotlin, bigdecimal

I read somewhere that the deciding committee of Java decided that a `setPrecision` method on `BigDecimal` would be dumb, since it already has `setScale`.

What is even dumber is to have API users have methods like this in their code:

```
private fun getBigDecimalWith16DigitPrecision(value: BigDecimal): BigDecimal {
    return when {
        value < BigDecimal.ONE -> value.setScale(16, RoundingMode.HALF_UP)
        value < BigDecimal(10) -> value.setScale(15, RoundingMode.HALF_UP)
        value < BigDecimal(100) -> value.setScale(14, RoundingMode.HALF_UP)
        value < BigDecimal(1000) -> value.setScale(13, RoundingMode.HALF_UP)
        value < BigDecimal(10000) -> value.setScale(12, RoundingMode.HALF_UP)
        else -> value.setScale(11, RoundingMode.HALF_UP)
    }
}
```

Which doesn't even cover all cases.

Comment: As I see it that Java committee owes me for those ~10 lines of code, that I now have to subtract from the total no. of lines I can effectively maintain

Comment: What would this look like if `BigDecimal` had a `setPrecision` method? Not getting it.

Comment: I guess this is a pretty rare example.

Comment: @ernest_k E.g. `BigDecimal("33.23").setPrecision(5) == BigDecimal("33.230")`, `BigDecimal("33.23").setPrecision(2) == BigDecimal("33")`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just one line, since your scale needs to change by exactly as much as precision does:

```
fun BigDecimal.setPrecision(newPrecision: Int) = setScale(scale() + (newPrecision - precision()), RoundingMode.HALF_UP)
```

Or alternatively (more obvious, but less efficient):

```
fun BigDecimal.setPrecision(newPrecision: Int) = BigDecimal(toPlainString(), MathContext(newPrecision, RoundingMode.HALF_UP))
```

Answer (score 1):

If all you're looking for is a simpler (more concise) version of your code, then you can simplify it by computing the scale (`16 -  log10(value)`, or `11`, whichever is greater):

```
return value.setScale((int) Math.max(11, 16 - Math.log10(value.doubleValue())),
                      RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
```